# PyCharm Alt+Click to get variable value

Tags: debugging, pycharm

Before PyCharm 4, I used to be able to `alt+click` a variable name while debugging and a would pop up window that lets me inspect he value of that variable. I am addicted to that feature, and now it is gone in PyCharm 4 (although my colleague claims it is still there). What changed? Does the feature still exists? Do I need to enable it explicitly?

PS The window I am talking about is different to the one you get when you hover over the variable name as it doesn't close when you accidentally move the mouse outside of it. I also know about watches and the interactive IPython console, but I find alt+click much faster and intuitive.

Comment: It apparently is replaced by Ctrl+f1 - hover the mouse you get the floating one and hit frigging Ctrl+f1 (if it does not disappear, whereupon it takes ages to reappear). It's so annoying - I am not even sure i do it right and half of the time the floating preview disappears and/or Ctrl+f1 does not work. Real Question is how the heck we get back Alt+Click

Comment: See my edited answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I created an issue - let's see what they say:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17758

It can be done hurrah:

> go to 'Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views' and disable the option 'Show value tooltip'